# On IN for multiple rows MYSQL , is that possible?

Tags: mysql

Trying to convert the following statement :

```
DELETE FROM products WHERE productid1 IN (5,6) OR productid2 IN (5,6);
```

into :

```
DELETE FROM products WHERE (productid1 OR productid2 ) IN (5,6);
```

Does not seem to work.

Is that possible actually?

Comment: What is the goal of changing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible; you have to repeat the IN().

`(productid1 OR productid2)` actually evaluates to a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM products WHERE productid1 IN (5,6);
DELETE FROM products WHERE  productid2 IN (5,6);
```

Would do the trick.